# Enable Chromium flags from the shell

Tags: chromium

In Chromium, command-line options can be enabled by browsing to `chrome://flags` and setting "Enable command line on non-rooted devices" to "Enabled".

However, is there a way to do this programmatically (i.e., from the shell)?  I need to enable this flag as part of my automatic tests.

Comment: So you've tried [ADB Shell Input Events](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7789826/295004)?

Comment: You mean send the input codes to type on the screen?

Comment: Input or tap/swipe events to reach what you need.